# a::after at 100% width is much larger than a

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pseudo-element

I'm stuck figuring out how I can get ::after to fill the available space inside an anchor.

https://jsfiddle.net/riegersn/g5vhaxa8/

```
.nsfw::after {
  content: "NSFW";
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c42c00;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like so ?

```
.nsfw {
   position:relative;
}

.nsfw::after {
  content: "NSFW";
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c42c00;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, my anchor wasn't relative. Thanks!